# Is there a database of stretches?

Tags: stretching

I'm looking for an online digital database (or encyclopedia of sorts, preferably free but open to paid options as well) of all the types of stretching (static, dynamic, PNF, etc).

Big plus if there's videos/pictures with detailed descriptions.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of previous posts asking for stretches.  You should consider reforming your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.gotrom.com/ or   https://stretchtherapy.net .

As a disclaimer, I have not subscribed to either of these paid sites.  I have been stretching for years, and I have put together my own personal "data base", meaning that I have my own routine.   So I dont' need to spend money on paid sites.  However, I've listened to Kit Laughlin at Stretch Therapy, and I like a lot of what he says.

On my journey to my own stretching routine, I have looked far and wide.  There is no one source.   Sometimes, I find a fantastic new stretch in some obscure place.  As examples, I'm going to suggest two stretches that are very obscure.   Here is a [stretch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZVHMbRo6rE) for your deep external hip rotators.  Fantastic stretch, but you need a padded table, which very few gyms have.  Fortunately, my gym has one.  The latest stretch in my routine is the [Butchers Block](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhhaK3nDbbA) stretch.  This was exceedingly difficult for me at the start.  Again, you need to find the right piece of equipment to get into the position.

In my opinion, stretching is still very much an underdeveloped area of fitness. As a result, you will have to do a lot of your own searching.  It  will take time to put together a routine.  There is no shortcut.  I could send you more examples of stretches by personal email if you like.